# How can I get HWND from String?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I have many windows with same names, For example Calculator.

```
User32Extra.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null,"Calculator")
```

The above Script gives me HWND of first Calculator found.

I have used EnumWindows to find all the HWNDs.

```
final HashMap<HWND,String> hm=new HashMap<HWND,String>();  
User32.INSTANCE.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {

     @Override
     public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg) {
         HWND hWnd2 = new HWND(hWnd);
        byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
        User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
        String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();

        if (!wText.isEmpty() && User32.INSTANCE.IsWindowVisible(hWnd2) && wText.equals("Calculator")) {
            hm.put(hWnd2,wText);
        }
        return true;
     }
  }, null);

for(HWND hwnd:hm.keySet()){
   System.out.println(hwnd.toString());
}
```

The above script gives output as

> native@0x20816
>
> native@0x50362
>
> native@0x1206ae

I don't have access of this HashMap in another program. I know only the String value of HWND.
Is it possible to cast `native@0x20816` String to HWND?

If so How can I do that? Please help..

Comment: Why are you converting a pointer to a string in the first place? Stop doing that and you won't need to parse the text back to a pointer.

Comment: I am sending this string to flex app where pointer or hwnd class is not defined. I have to call functions in Java from actionscript to perform some operations on hwnd.

Comment: So you're trying to provide actionscript with unique (string) keys with which you can reference native windows?

Comment: Yes (for identifying window uniquely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String hwndString = "native@0xa021c";
HWND temp = new HWND();
temp.setPointer(new Pointer(Long.decode(hwndString.substring(7))));
if(User32.INSTANCE.IsWindow(temp)){
     //This is a valid window
}
else{
     // Invalid Window
}
```

Comment: I still cannot understand why you convert from pointer to string and then back again, why you prefix with `native@`. Your answer is pure Java.

Answer (score 2):

If you are coding entirely in this Java program then it is pointless to convert the window handle to a text representation. Simply use the `HWND` value directly.

If in fact the issue is that you send the text to some other party, and need to obtain the numeric value of the window handle, then simply convert the text to a numeric value. I see little point in prefixing the text with `native@` and the hexadecimal prefix `0x` is probably also superfluous. The two parties can simple agree that the value will always be passed as hexadecimal. Presumably you know enough about Java and the other programming languages that are involved to be able to convert between numeric values and hexadecimal text.

Comment: `native@0xXXXX` is emitted as the string representation of a native pointer by JNA.

Comment: @technomage Clearly. Not difficult to create a string representation without the prefix though.